# FREECODECAMP React APP VS code vulnerability issues in node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS code and was trying to code a project for `FREECODECAMP`. The project is a random quote machine and it's my first time coding a react project. I have been following a YouTube video while coding and after I finished the part where everything was functional my child hits the keyboard and I ended up in another file of code. Now the code works until I click the button change quotes. It crashes says it can't read the length the parsed array and it shows that I have a bunch of vulnerabilities. I've have been trying to figure this out for days but nothing. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything, I tried to run `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`, and I think I made it worse. Now it says that I have 132 vulnerabilities and I just want to finish learning how to code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

let quoteDBUrl = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";


function App() {


  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("Money is the Motivation")
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("Lil Wayne")
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(0)
  const [quotesArray, setQuotesArray] = useState(null)

  const fetchQuotes = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const parsedJSON = await response.json();
    setQuotesArray(parsedJSON.quotes)
    console.log(parsedJSON)
  }

  //const quotesArray =[{quote: "Dude", author:"Shay"},{quote: "Blood", author:"ken"},{quote: "Tears", author:"Boobie"}];
    useEffect((quoteDBUrl) => {
      fetchQuotes(quoteDBUrl)
    }, [quoteDBUrl]);
   

  const changeQuote = () => {
    let randomInteger = Math.floor(quotesArray.length* Math.random());
    setRandomNumber(randomInteger)
    setQuote(quotesArray[randomInteger].quote)
    setAuthor(quotesArray[randomInteger].author)
  }

 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Random Quote Machine
        </p>

        <p>"{quote}"</p>
        <p>-{author}</p>
        <button onClick={() => changeQuote()}>Change Quote</button>
        
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image][image][image][image]

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall, I have tried to audit fix, and I tried to manually delete files and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't express myself well hehe.

What happens is that in the useEffect hook you are sending a parameter.
And you never actually call the hook, it runs by itself.
Inside the hook it is using the parameter you assigned but it doesn't exist.

The hook should look like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchQuotes(quoteDBUrl)
}, [quoteDBUrl]);
```

Comment: woooow lol thank you so much i thought i broke the program